# Dismiss two TableViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a `View` that has a button in it, something like this `Button---(segue)---> TableViewControllerNO1-----(segue)-->TableViewControllerNO2`. In the `TableViewControllerNO2` I delete all the rows by pressing a `button` and I want after I delete the rows to return to the first `View`, the one before the `TableViewControllerNO1`, how can I dismiss the two `TableViewControllers` from `TableViewControllerNO2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a cool method to do this: `popToViewController`

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

So the important is inject a reference to that `viewController`.

Otherwise you can also do:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

but the right way is the first.

Comment: It worked, here is my code how I did it :
NSArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
        for( int i=0;i<[viewControllers count];i++){
            id obj=[viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
            if([obj isKindOfClass:[BucatarSauOspatarViewController class]]){
                [[self navigationController] popToViewController:obj animated:YES];
                return;

Comment: That can be another solution (more expensive) to get your viewController ;) . Or if you know that you want pop 2 viewController: `UIViewController *obj = viewControllers[[viewControllers count]-1-2];`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated` (assuming you are using a navigation controller). This would take you all the way back to the root view controller in your navigation stack, and use the standard animation.

Comment: my aplication is like this View1--->View2--->TableViewController1---->TableViewController2, and the command returns me to View1 but I want to return to View2 from TableViewController2